# Python. Transformar string de um objeto em uma lista

Tags: python

Como eu posso conseguir pegar a string `'banana morango abacaxi'` e transformá-la em uma lista, separando cada fruta como um item?

Código:

```
class Exemplo(object):

      def __init__(self, atributo:str = None):
          self.atributo = atributo
```

Testando com um exemplo:

```
objeto = Exemplo('banana morango abacaxi')

print(objeto)
```

Resultado:

```
<__main__.Exemplo object at 0x7fd598aea590>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode definir um método `__iter__`, que retorna algo "iterável", que pode ser usado em loops ou transformado em lista, e o método `__str__`, que retorna uma string, pra quando alguma outra função precisar transformar seu objeto em string essa `__str__` será chamada, e, no caso, vai fazer a representação de string da nossa nova lista:

```py
class Exemplo:
    def __init__(self, atributo:str = None):
        self.atributo = atributo


    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.atributo.split())

    def __str__(self):
        return str(list(self))

    
print(list(Exemplo('banana morango abacaxi')))


print()

for item in Exemplo('cafe feijão'):
    print(item)

print()

obj = Exemplo('arroz farinha')

print(obj)

for item in obj:
    print(item)
```

Saída:

```
['banana', 'morango', 'abacaxi']

cafe
feijão

['arroz', 'farinha']
arroz
farinha
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que queria!